# How can I remove the zero padding at the start of a .mp3 file generated by ffmpeg conversion?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

After reading [this](https://lame.sourceforge.io/tech-FAQ.txt) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286390/why-does-libmp3lame-add-zeros-to-the-start-of-the-mp3),  I understand that the `.mp3` encoder appends zeros at the start and at the end of an audio.

With this approach, the encoder can pass a sliding analysis window through the initial and final audio samples, just like in the rest of the audio.

This sliding window is associated with a Fourier Transform-like algorithm, but I will not get into this technical detail.

My problem is: When I generate an `.mp3` with `ffmpeg` like:

```
MacBook-Air-de-Miguel:faixas miguel$ ffmpeg -i primeira_caf.caf primeira_agora_vai.mp3
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[caf @ 0x7fe205009000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, caf, from 'primeira_caf.caf':
  Duration: 00:00:08.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1414 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to 'primeira_agora_vai.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libmp3lame
size=     137kB time=00:00:08.75 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=  61x    
video:0kB audio:137kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.180156%
```

my generated `.mp3` has +- 50ms of latency. I'm not 100% sure that all this latency is caused by the zero padding that I mentioned.

Converting `.caf` to other audio formats like `.wav` and `.ogg` do not give me this problem.

Considering `.mp3` as a constraint, is there any simple way to generate a `.mp3` with zero latency? Maybe a `ffmpeg` argument that cuts off the zero padding at the start?

If not, is it possible to do it manually? How can I know or calculate how many samples should be cut off?

I have also tried `sox`. It adds 25ms of latency instead of 50ms.

Comment: Lossy codecs, particularly MP3, are not great if this level of timing accuracy matters to you.  In any case, you might be able to make use of "gapless" MP3, where there is some extra metadata added.  I don't remember the details or I'd answer this question, but that should point you in the right direction if you still want to use MP3.

Comment: Hi, Brad. Thanks! I'll probably look towards a solution that compress the audio (so I can send it to a server without consuming too much space from my database and doesn't consume the users data stream), maybe even a non-playable compressed format. Do you have any suggestions on that?